# Assimp CodeBlocks redefinition and undefined references

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, codeblocks, assimp

I am currently trying to compile Assimp ( asset import library. Can be found [here](http://assimp.org/) ) and when i was trying to compile using CodeBlocks alot of errors popped up.

```
||=== Build: all in Assimp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|39|warning: "D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|30|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|40|warning: "D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|31|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|41|warning: "D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|32|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|42|warning: "D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|33|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|43|warning: "D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|34|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|44|warning: "D3DCREATE_MIXED_VERTEXPROCESSING" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|35|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|57|warning: "D3DSPD_IUNKNOWN" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|36|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|63|warning: "D3D_SDK_VERSION" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|29|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|65|warning: "D3DENUM_NO_WHQL_LEVEL" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|70|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|68|warning: "D3DPRESENT_BACK_BUFFERS_MAX" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|71|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|69|warning: "D3DSGR_NO_CALIBRATION" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|37|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|70|warning: "D3DSGR_CALIBRATE" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|38|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|73|warning: "MAKE_D3DHRESULT" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|39|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|74|warning: "MAKE_D3DSTATUS" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|40|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|79|warning: "D3D_OK" redefined|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|41|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|185|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3D9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|121|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3D9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|289|error: 'D3DDISPLAYMODEFILTER' does not name a type|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|290|error: 'D3DDISPLAYMODEFILTER' does not name a type|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|291|error: 'D3DDISPLAYMODEEX' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|292|error: 'D3DDISPLAYMODEEX' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|292|error: 'D3DDISPLAYROTATION' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|293|error: 'D3DDISPLAYMODEEX' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|354|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DVolume9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|551|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DVolume9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|410|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DSwapChain9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|595|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DSwapChain9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|481|error: 'D3DPRESENTSTATS' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|482|error: 'D3DDISPLAYMODEEX' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|482|error: 'D3DDISPLAYROTATION' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|530|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DResource9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|636|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DResource9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|586|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DSurface9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|680|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DSurface9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|663|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DVertexBuffer9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|742|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DVertexBuffer9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|731|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DIndexBuffer9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|795|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DIndexBuffer9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|799|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DBaseTexture9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|848|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DBaseTexture9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|876|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DCubeTexture9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|910|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DCubeTexture9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|972|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DTexture9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|987|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DTexture9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1067|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DVolumeTexture9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|1064|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DVolumeTexture9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1162|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|1141|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1200|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DVertexShader9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|1167|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DVertexShader9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1238|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DPixelShader9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|1193|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DPixelShader9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1276|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DStateBlock9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|1219|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DStateBlock9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1317|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DQuery9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|1248|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DQuery9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1364|error: redefinition of 'struct IDirect3DDevice9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3d9.h|183|error: previous definition of 'struct IDirect3DDevice9'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1886|error: 'D3DCOMPOSERECTSOP' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1901|error: 'D3DDISPLAYMODEEX' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1902|error: 'D3DDISPLAYMODEEX' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3d9.h|1902|error: 'D3DDISPLAYROTATION' has not been declared|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3dx9xof.h|75|error: expected identifier before string constant|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3dx9xof.h|75|error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\d3dx9xof.h|75|error: cannot declare parameter to be of abstract type 'IUnknown'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 15 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 49 second(s)) ===|
```

I **first** had to fix some file paths, first with direct parts but after another compile with cmake it worked with just adjusted search paths.

Can you please assist me in successfully building this project?

EDIT:
I changed the Include paths because there were 2 paths for 1 file. However these errors showed up afterwards:

```
||=== Build: all in Assimp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|75|error: expected identifier before string constant|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|75|error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|75|error: cannot declare parameter to be of abstract type 'IUnknown'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\unknwn.h|24|note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'IUnknown':|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\unknwn.h|26|note:     virtual HRESULT IUnknown::QueryInterface(const IID&, void**)|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\unknwn.h|27|note:     virtual ULONG IUnknown::AddRef()|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\unknwn.h|28|note:     virtual ULONG IUnknown::Release()|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h||In function 'int DECLARE_INTERFACE_IID_(ID3DXFile, IUnknown, int)':|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|75|error: '<anonymous>' has incomplete type|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|66|error: forward declaration of 'struct ID3DXFile'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|78|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|78|error: function 'HRESULT QueryInterface(const IID&, void**)' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|79|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|79|error: function 'ULONG AddRef()' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|80|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|80|error: function 'ULONG Release()' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|83|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|83|error: function 'HRESULT CreateEnumObject(const void*, D3DXF_FILELOADOPTIONS, ID3DXFileEnumObject**)' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|85|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|85|error: function 'HRESULT CreateSaveObject(const void*, D3DXF_FILESAVEOPTIONS, D3DXF_FILEFORMAT, ID3DXFileSaveObject**)' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|86|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|86|error: function 'HRESULT RegisterTemplates(const void*, SIZE_T)' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|87|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|87|error: function 'HRESULT RegisterEnumTemplates(ID3DXFileEnumObject*)' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|92|error: expected identifier before string constant|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|92|error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|92|error: cannot declare parameter to be of abstract type 'IUnknown'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h||In function 'int DECLARE_INTERFACE_IID_(ID3DXFileSaveObject, IUnknown, int)':|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|92|error: '<anonymous>' has incomplete type|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|67|error: forward declaration of 'struct ID3DXFileSaveObject'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|92|error: conflicting declaration of C function 'int DECLARE_INTERFACE_IID_(ID3DXFileSaveObject, IUnknown, int)'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|75|note: previous declaration 'int DECLARE_INTERFACE_IID_(ID3DXFile, IUnknown, int)'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|95|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|95|error: function 'HRESULT QueryInterface(const IID&, void**)' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|96|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|96|error: function 'ULONG AddRef()' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|97|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|97|error: function 'ULONG Release()' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|99|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|99|error: function 'HRESULT GetFile(ID3DXFile**)' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|101|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|101|error: function 'HRESULT AddDataObject(const GUID&, const char*, const GUID*, SIZE_T, const void*, ID3DXFileSaveData**)' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|102|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|102|error: function 'HRESULT Save()' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|107|error: expected identifier before string constant|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|107|error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|107|error: cannot declare parameter to be of abstract type 'IUnknown'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h||In function 'int DECLARE_INTERFACE_IID_(ID3DXFileSaveData, IUnknown, int)':|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|107|error: '<anonymous>' has incomplete type|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|68|error: forward declaration of 'struct ID3DXFileSaveData'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|107|error: conflicting declaration of C function 'int DECLARE_INTERFACE_IID_(ID3DXFileSaveData, IUnknown, int)'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|92|note: previous declaration 'int DECLARE_INTERFACE_IID_(ID3DXFileSaveObject, IUnknown, int)'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|107|error: conflicting declaration of C function 'int DECLARE_INTERFACE_IID_(ID3DXFileSaveData, IUnknown, int)'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|75|note: previous declaration 'int DECLARE_INTERFACE_IID_(ID3DXFile, IUnknown, int)'|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|110|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|110|error: function 'HRESULT QueryInterface(const IID&, void**)' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|111|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|111|error: function 'ULONG AddRef()' is initialized like a variable|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|112|error: 'virtual' outside class declaration|
C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\d3dx9xof.h|112|error: function 'ULONG Release()' is initialized like a variable|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 0):

You included two folders whit same header files:

> C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\

and

> C:\Users\MoustacheSpy\Desktop\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\

Revise your -I option in project options.

Comment: I dont know. do you try to compile this? (https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.markdown)